# Best way to enumerate collection when elements may be deleted during enumeration

Tags: c#, .net, collections, enumeration

There is a typical collection of some class objects e.g. `string` for a simplicity

```
IList<string> collection = new List<string>();
```

During the program flow some function needs to operate on the collection, process class object and depending on the result of operation remove processed class object from collection.

E.g. following example of strings if string is "failed" then remove that item

```
foreach (string str in collection)
{
    // operate on the current class object
    // if str is not valid
    if (str == "failed")
        collection.Remove(str);
}
```

By all means that leads to exception.
What is the best way to loop thru all elements having ability to remove it during enumeration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do an indexed for loop, but do it backwards, because when you delete members the indexes upstream get changed.

e.g, for your string collection example:

```
for (int i = collection.Count() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    // do some other stuff, then ...

    if (collection[i] == "failed")
        collection.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

NB: if you use a forward for-loop, it may appear to work at first, but it will skip an item after each remove (because of the way indexes get renumbered after a remove). So a common symptom of that bug is that removes appear to work until you get two adjacent ones. That can be quite a confusing bug. Not that its ever happened to me *cough*

Comment: This is perhaps the only way to modify a collection as you're iterating through it.

Comment: This is the same as what I do. A guy at my previous job showed me and I couldn't believe I never thought of doing it.

Comment: thank you very much, the backward loop is the elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

For List<> collections you can use RemoveAll.

```
collection.RemoveAll ( item => item == "failed" );
```

For generic IEnumerable<> collections you can create a new collection with the items removed.

```
var newList = collection.Where ( item => item != "failed" );
```

As it is lazily evaluated you are not actually creating two collections in memory, rather a state machine that will enumerate through the non failed items as needed.

Comment: This is probably even better than a loop.

Comment: We do not know in advance if class object in a collection is failed. On each item in a collection some processing is done, and if operation failed, it is removed.

Answer (score 0):

If the collection is a `List` or `Set`, you can use an indexed `for` loop and perform the deletion.

Comment: That code gives wierd results:
  
     List<string> collection = new List<string>();
     collection.Add("one");
     collection.Add("second");
     collection.Add("third");                        
     for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++)
     {
         string v = collection[i];
         if (v == "one")
             collection.Remove(v);
     }

Comment: In C# you need to have a decrementing for loop not an incrementing one, otherwise items get skipped when you remove (due to indexes changing). See my answer for details.